# How to overcome the winform's Control.DrawToBitmap() method large size limitation

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an desktop application using C#, Winforms, and MS Visual Studio 2010. In the application, I have to take the screenshot of a panel of a form and save the image in disc. The panel size can be large. I have used Panel.DrawToBitmap() method to save the image of the panel. But, when the panel size is too large, it throws exception. I have found in msdn ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that for large size control, the method Control.DrawToBitmap will not work. Is there any alternative way, I can achieve the similar behavior overcoming the size limitation. It is to be noted the panel size can vary.

Update: I have found alternative of Control.DrawToBitmap : [WebBrowser.DrawToBitmap() or other methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434156/webbrowser-drawtobitmap-or-other-methods/2434231#2434231).
But, it only captures the visible part of the control.

Comment: What numbers are we talking about? Can you give us the sizes you may need?

Comment: Is this happening consistently, or first after your program has been running for a while? In the latter case, maybe you need to dispose of some resources - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996335/drawtobitmap-system-argumentexception-parameter-is-not-valid

Comment: *"How to overcome [whatever winforms limitation]"* - use current, non deprecated technology. winforms doesn't support anything.

Comment: @HighCore: WinForms deprecated? Where does it say that?

Comment: @RenniePet is COBOL deprecated? where does it say that?

Comment: @Taw: around height greater than 20000 and width greater than 9000.

Comment: @RenniePet: I have alteady seen that. My problem is quite simple to reproduce. You can just create a winform application add a form with a panel with big size. in the code call panel.DrawToBitmap inside try block and catch the ecception.

Comment: @Highcore: please don't bring back unnecessary discussion here degressing from the topic

Comment: @rksajib I'm actually telling you the solution, not brining unnecessary discussion. If you want to overcome winforms' limitations, then use current technology. Period.

Comment: "height greater than 20000 and width greater than 9000" ... Now I'm curious, what kind of screen has that many pixels? Or are you talking about a Panel control where only a small portion of it is visible, but you want to grab the whole panel anyway?

Comment: @HighCore: It's an old application with lots of legacy code, switching from winforms is not feasible right now.

Comment: @RenniePet: The screen is usual screen. Yes. The panel control sometimes is so large that we have to use horizontal and vertical scroll bar to see other portions and Yes, I want to grab the whole panel.

Answer (score 2):

This question had me confused about quite a few things..

Here is a solution that writes an image file from a `Panel` of rather large sizes..

One of the limiting factors is the size of the resulting Bitmap. I have tested for sizes of up to `12.5k * 25k` and found it to work fine; the sizes may depend on your machine, though. I think you need quite some contiguous memory to create such a large `Bitmap`.

The other problem is, as your title suggests, indeed with the `DrawToBitmap` method itself. It looks as if it can't reliably write onto large Bitmaps, which is why I had to buffer its results in a temporary Bitmap. Nor can it work if any dimension of the control is over some size, maybe 4k, but maybe not..

The solution first creates a `Bitmap` of the `Panel`'s size. Then it creates a temporary `Panel` to house the large `Panel`. This container it small enough for `DrawToBitmap` to work.

Then it loops over the width and height, moving the large `Panel` up and left, pasting the portions `DrawToBitmap` brings back, step by step into the large `Bitmap`.

Finally it writes it back as `PNG` for best readability and size..

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(largePanel.ClientSize.Width, largePanel.ClientSize.Height);

    DrawToBitmap(largePanel, bmp);      // the patchwork method

    bmp.Save(yourFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    bmp.Dispose();                      // get rid of the big one!

    GC.Collect();                       // not sure why, but it helped
}


void DrawToBitmap(Control ctl, Bitmap bmp)
{
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;         // yes it takes a while
    Panel p = new Panel();               // the containing panel
    Point oldLocation = ctl.Location;    // 
    p.Location = Point.Empty;            //
    this.Controls.Add(p);                //

    int maxWidth = 2000;                 // you may want to try other sizes
    int maxHeight = 2000;                //

    Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(maxWidth, maxHeight);  // the buffer

    p.Height = maxHeight;               // set up the..
    p.Width = maxWidth;                 // ..container

    ctl.Location = new Point(0, 0);     // starting point
    ctl.Parent = p;                     // inside the container
    p.Show();                           // 
    p.BringToFront();                   //

    // we'll draw onto the large bitmap with G
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    for (int y = 0; y < ctl.Height; y += maxHeight)
    {
        ctl.Top = -y;                   // move up
        for (int x = 0; x < ctl.Width; x += maxWidth)
        {
            ctl.Left = -x;             // move left
            p.DrawToBitmap(bmp2, new Rectangle(0, 0, maxWidth, maxHeight));
            G.DrawImage(bmp2, x, y);   // patch together
        }
    }

    ctl.Location = p.Location;         // restore..
    ctl.Parent = this;                 // form layout <<<==== ***
    p.Dispose();                       // clean up

    Cursor = Cursors.Default;          // done
}
```

I have drawn a few things onto the `Panel` and thrown in a few hundred `Buttons` and the result looks seamless. Can't post it, for obvious reasons..

***** Note:**  If your Panel doesn't sit on the form you should change `this` to the real `Parent`!