# Winforms - how to print the whole of a form, including unseen parts?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have a windows forms project written in C#.  The main form has a `TabControl` on it and there is a requirement for one of the users to be able to print one of the `TabPages`.  The form is very long and I use a vertical scroll bar.  The whole of the form needs to be able to be printed.

I have tried using the `DrawToBitmap` method to convert to a bitmap first, but this will only include the portion of the form that the user can see.  Some other solutions I have tried involve screen capturing, which has the same issue.

How can I print out, or get an image, of the whole of the tab page, including the parts the user only sees when they scroll down?

Comment: Not sure about your case, but in general print outs of transaction is more about the information of the transaction than about the graphical image. That said, consider generating a report with all desired information.

Comment: @EmmadKareem this printout is full of images, as well as textual information.  I am going to have to do it as a PDF report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather simple for any control including `TabControls` and `TabPages` but not `Forms`.

All you need to do is enlarge the relevant controls enough to show all their content. (They **don't** have to be actually **visible** on screen.)

Here is an example:

```
tabControl1.Height = 10080;
tabPage2.Height = 10050;
dataGridView1.Height = 10000;

dataGridView1.Rows.Add(3000);
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)  dataGridView1[0, i].Value = i;

using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(tabControl1.Width , tabControl1.Height ))
{
    tabControl1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, tabControl1.ClientRectangle);
    bmp.Save("D:\\xxxx.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

This saves the full content of the `DataGridView`, the `TabPage` and the `TabControl`..

**Note:** that this will not work with forms, which can't much exceed the screen dimensions..

**Update:**  Here is code that saves a form with vertical scrolling by patching several bitmaps together. It can, of course be expanded to include horizontal scrolling as well. I have coded a similar solution for larger Panels [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360110/how-to-overcome-the-winforms-control-drawtobitmap-method-large-size-limitatio/27406432?s=1|0.5539#27406432)

```
static void saveLargeForm(Form form, string fileName)
{
    // yes it may take a while
    form.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    // allocate target bitmap and a buffer bitmap
    Bitmap target = new Bitmap(form.DisplayRectangle.Width, form.DisplayRectangle.Height);
    Bitmap buffer = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height);
    // the vertical pointer
    int y = 0;
    var vsc = form.VerticalScroll;
    vsc.Value = 0;
    form.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 0);
    // the scroll amount
    int l = vsc.LargeChange;

    Rectangle srcRect = ClientBounds(form);
    Rectangle destRect = Rectangle.Empty;
    bool done = false;

    // we'll draw onto the large bitmap with G
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(target))
    {
        while (!done)
        {
            destRect = new Rectangle(0, y, srcRect.Width, srcRect.Height);
            form.DrawToBitmap(buffer, new Rectangle(0, 0, form.Width, form.Height));
            G.DrawImage(buffer, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);   
            int v = vsc.Value;
            vsc.Value = vsc.Value + l;
            form.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(form.AutoScrollPosition.X, vsc.Value + l);
            int delta = vsc.Value - v;
            done = delta < l;
            y += delta;
        }
        destRect = new Rectangle(0, y, srcRect.Width, srcRect.Height);
        form.DrawToBitmap(buffer, new Rectangle(0, 0, form.Width, form.Height));
        G.DrawImage(buffer, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    // write result to disc and clean up
    target.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    target.Dispose();   
    buffer.Dispose();      
    GC.Collect();          // not sure why, but it helped
    form.Cursor = Cursors.Default;    
}
```

It makes use of a helper function to determine the the net size of the virtual client rectangle, ie excluding borders, title and scrollbar:

```
static Rectangle ClientBounds(Form f)
{
    Rectangle rc = f.ClientRectangle;
    Rectangle rb = f.Bounds;
    int sw = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
    var vsc = f.VerticalScroll;
    int bw = (rb.Width - rc.Width - (vsc.Visible ? sw : 0) ) / 2;
    int th = (rb.Height - rc.Height) - bw * 2;
    return new Rectangle(bw, th + bw, rc.Width, rc.Height );
}
```

Comment: thanks but this didn't work for me.  The height of the tab control and tab page won't change.  Even when I assign them in the code `Height =` if you put a breakpoint in afterwards you can see the assignment has had no effect.  The image which results is still truncated at the bottom of the visible screen area.

Comment: That sounds very strange. I works fine here. Where do you call the code from? - The other option I know of involves patching pieces of scrolled parts together. This maens tha you need to control the scolling precisely..

Comment: See my update for a solution, that includes the full (vertically scrolled) display height of the form!

Comment: I get an exception when I run this `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Value of '110' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.` The problem is in the line `vsc.Value = vsc.Value + l`

Comment: Hm, can you tell me the sizes involved? Where/when  did you call the code? May you should change `vsc.Value = vsc.Value + l;` to `vsc.Value = Math.Min(vsc.Maximum, vsc.Value + l);`..

Comment: thanks, I've tried this out in a "hello world" example and now it doesn't error - I'll test it in my production code tomorrow and see if it works :)

Comment: It works, thanks!  I have made some small changes.  1) The edit @TaW suggested in the above comment.  2) The methods can taker any ScrollableControl as a parameter, it does not have to be a Form.  3) I cache the scroll position at the start of the code and reset it to that at the end.