# Get ScreenShot of Full Windows Form Which Has Scrollbar C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I am looking to get full height picture of form but I am only able to get the screenshot of only whats visible but I want to get screenshot of full form which has content beyond visible part.

I already saw there was solution for listbox [How can I take a screenshot of a Winforms control/form in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493591/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-winforms-control-form-in-c) but i am looking generate full page image of form I can't quite figure it out.

This my current code:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height);
      form.DrawToBitmap(image, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), image.Size));
      return image;
```

Comment: answer provided on other question about listbox and I am looking for winforms

Comment: I had answered a similar question but can't find the post :-( - What it boiled down to is this: Take shots of the portion shown with drawtobitmap, then scroll down take anther shot etc. finally stitch together! It worked quite well..

Comment: @TaW thanks for response in the mean time if you can find your answer it wold great :)

Comment: Found it! [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918450/winforms-how-to-print-the-whole-of-a-form-including-unseen-parts/30924473?s=1|0.1069#30924473)...